# Why does Pandas qcut give me unequal sized bins?

Tags: python, pandas

[Pandas docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.qcut.html) have this to say about the qcut function:

> Discretize variable into equal-sized buckets based on rank or based on sample quantiles.

So I would expect this code to give me 4 bins of 10 values each:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(4242)

y = pd.Series(np.random.randint(low=1, high=10, size=40))
quartiles = pd.qcut(y, 4, labels=['1st', '2nd', '3rd', '4th'])

print('Quartiles:')
print(quartiles.value_counts(sort=False))

y.groupby(quartiles).agg(['count', 'mean']).plot(kind='bar');
```

But instead I get this:

```
Quartiles:
1st    14
2nd     6
3rd    11
4th     9
dtype: int64
```

[graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuWvY.png)

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I think equal values get the same label, and you've got a lot of equal values.

Comment: @user2357112 That makes sense, thanks

Answer (score 2):

The reason this happens is because python doesn't know how to deal with 'boundary-line' cases, i.e. records that may fit first and second quartiles easily. A simple adjustment to your code will produce the desired result:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(4242)

y = pd.Series(np.random.randint(low=1, high=10, size=40))
quartiles = pd.qcut(y.rank(method = 'first'), 4, labels=['1st', '2nd', '3rd', '4th'])

print('Quartiles:')
print(quartiles.value_counts(sort=False))

y.groupby(quartiles).agg(['count', 'mean']).plot(kind='bar');
```

By stating the approach to be used by python using the `rank()` function, we give python a clear approach to handling records that cut across multiple bins. In this case, I've used `(method = 'first')` as the argument for the `rank()` function.

The output I get is as follows:

```
Quartiles:
1st    10
2nd    10
3rd    10
4th    10
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the boundaries of the bins highlights the problem stated inside the comments.

```
boundaries = [1, 2, 3.5, 6, 9]
```

These boundaries are correct. The code of pandas creates the values for the quantiles (inside qcut), first. Afterwards the samples are put into the bins. The range of 2s overlaps the boundary of the first quartile.
The reason for the third values is that the value below the threshold is a 3 and  the value above the threshold is a 4. The function quantile of pandas is called so that the boundary lies in between the two neighboring values.

**Concluding:** A concept like quantiles gets more and more appropriate, when there are a larger number of samples, so that more values are available fixing the boundaries.